# unable to create user postgres: role "postgres" does not exists

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation, role

i am on ubuntu 12.04 server and i am trying to install postgresql. As of now, i have successfully installed it but unable to configure it. I need to create a role to move ahead and i ran this command in terminal :

`root@hostname: createuser -s -r postgres`

and it said :

`createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

Fine, so i did :

`su - postgres`

and then tried again

`postgres@hostname: createuser -s -r postgres`

and i got the error

`createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

and i get the same error when i do

`psql -d dbname`

Its like a loop, i am unable to create a role `postgres` because a role `postgres` does not already exist.

How do i fix this ?

The postgres version seems to be 9.1.x and the ubuntu version is 12.10

Comment: What is the output of `sudo pg_lsclusters` ?

Comment: @A.H. The command `pg_lsclusters` was not found. It asked me to install `postgresql-common` package. I tried doing as root user and i got an error. Its tried removing `postgres-xc` and `dpkg: error processing postgres-xc (--remove):` and then it exit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out i had installed `postgres-xc` and `postgresql` on my machine. I had to knock off postgres-xc completely. And it was a little difficult to do that because, there was always an error `--purge remove postgres-xc` and the uninstallation could not continue.

There seems to be some kind of a packaging bug. ([details on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgres-xc/+bug/1084849)).

Eventually, i ended up doing [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgres-xc/+bug/1084849/comments/7) to make it work.

After that i uninstalled postgresql and installed it back to make it work.

Comment: I had a similar issue. When uninstalling postgresql, make sure to stop all postgres processes, delete the unix user `postgres`, and also delete the lock files in `/var/run/postgresql`.

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy thanks for that. I remember i had eventually solved by doing pretty much what you said. :)

Comment: postgres-xc apparently messed up my postgres setup as well. Same fix worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Read [postgresql tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-createdb.html) it doesn't matter if it's Ubuntu or other Linux.

EDIT
before creating role or anything else on fresh install you need to create database cluster: have you created it?

```
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

You need to be logged as user `postgres` on linux machine. [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/creating-cluster.html) is more info.

Comment: yeah. I am following the steps but i am unable to create a user. The role `postgres` does not exist to create the role `postgres`. Thats what is confusing me. any idea ?

Comment: @Ladislav: Debian (and therefore also Ubuntu) has custom scripts and conventions for managing PostgreSQL databases and clusters. Using the plain PG-commands will do more harm than it is good. Especially for non-experts.

Comment: @A.H. not know about debian and ubuntu, i'm using slackware. with `initdb` you won't harm your instalation, it's for creating database cluster. it will create files in `/usr/local/pgsql/data`, if something goes wrong you can remove it and go from start.

Comment: The problem: This new database might not be picked up at reboot. And having multiple database versions in parallel will not work. Multiple clusters will not work. And so on. Do **you** want to sort out the mess via chat if _anything_ will not work?

Comment: @A.H.i would love to chat and seek help !