# role "postgres" does not exist; cannot createuser

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am on Linux Mint Cinnamon 2.2.16.

During the process of getting Rails up and running, I am having problems with Postgres.

```
postgres@BL ~ $ psql --version
psql (Postgres-XC) 1.1
(based on PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

I was unable to get anything working under my usual username, so I changed to the default user using

```
sudo su - postgres
```

I cannot get anything to work with createuser.

```
postgres@BL ~ $ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

postgres@BL ~ $ createuser -s -U $USER
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

postgres@BL ~ $ sudo -u postgres createuser newname
Sorry, user postgres is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/createuser newname' as postgres on BL.

postgres@BL ~ $ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
postgres@BL ~ $ psql \l
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Comment: Try this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist

Comment: I get no output out of $ psql \l, instead gives me the same FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist.  Makes me think I have no users at all, but require a user to create a user...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thoroughly researching the problem and tearing out more than a few hairs, I decided this was some variation of a problem with packaging/installation, similar problem noted here:  [unable to create user postgres: role "postgres" does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591749/unable-to-create-user-postgres-role-postgres-does-not-exists)

I did a complete uninstall, as per below, and reinstalled without postgresql-xc

[How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu)

The new install had expected behavior with the user "postgres" and I was able to add myself as a superuser and create new databases.  After some post-installation finagling, Rails seems to be running and playing nice with postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate to psql as the superuser in order to manage users. 
For example

> psql -U root

Afterwards

> create user paige with password 'paige';

Comment: Unfortunately, getting the same error here.  

    postgres@BL ~ $ psql -U root
    psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: Do you remember the username you first used when installing postgres?

Comment: I don't believe I created a user with a unique name, though it did ask if I wanted to create a password for the "admin 'root' user", which I did.  Is there any other standard user name beside admin, root, user, or postgres ?